# AnimationVector Drawable not work

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

**animation vector**

this code work

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="translateX"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:valueFrom="-20"
    android:valueTo="20"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

but this code not work

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="fillColor"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:valueFrom="#ffffff"
    android:valueTo="#ff8400"
    android:valueType="colorType" />
```

why ? please help me

Comment: Please update your question with the code that doesn't work.